# Количество ресурсов MODX

Tags: php, modx

Сайт построен на **MODX**. Подскажите, каким способом можно посчитать количество неудаленных ресурсов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно так:

```
echo $modx->getCount('modResource', array('deleted:!=' => 1));
```

или так:

```
echo count($modx->getCollection('modResource', array('deleted:!=' => 1)));
```